# Why are models such as BERT or GPT-3 considered unsupervised learning during pre-training when there is an output (label)

Tags: machine-learning, bert-language-model, unsupervised-learning

I am not very experienced with unsupervised learning, but my general understanding is that in unsupervised learning, the model learns without there being an output. However, during pre-training in models such as BERT or GPT-3, it seems to me that there is an output. For example, in BERT, some of the tokens in the input sequence are masked. Then, the model will try to predict those words. Since we already know what those masked words originally were, we can compare that with the prediction to find the loss. Isn't this basically supervised learning?

Comment: related post https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/44943/what-technique-is-used-for-training-large-language-models-like-gpt

Answer (score 2):

Pre-trained language models typically leverage learning objectives that can be derived from the structure of the training data. As pointed out by @solitone, techniques like masked/causal language modelling allow the model to get supervision signals from the pre-training data, which greatly contributes to the success of PLMs and LLMs.

Another more acute terminology often referred to in the literature would be **self-supervised learning** as unsupervised learning traditionally refers to techniques like clustering.

Answer (score -1):

The pre-training phase of models like GPT is considered *unsupervised* because it learns from *unlabeled* data. In contrast, *supervised* learning relies on *labeled* data, which typically requires manual annotation.

Take document classification as an example. Imagine having tons of books, but none tell you their subjects. Labeling them for supervised learning would be hard, time-consuming, and expensive, and costly. Imagine having to go through each book and manually write down its subject.

This distinction is outlined in the [Improving Language Understanding
by Generative Pre-Training](https://cdn.openai.com/research-covers/language-unsupervised/language_understanding_paper.pdf) paper.

To tell the truth, I also thought the pre-training phase was supervised training. And interestingly, in this [video](https://youtu.be/bZQun8Y4L2A?si=_TLUqhQNvfwuyH7E&t=403) Andrej Karpathy explains the masked token can be used as a **source of supervision** to update the transformer's weights: